# Convert Dates with Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

i have a date in this format

May 30 2006 12:00AM

is there a  equivalent of strtotime() in mysql that will let me convert this to a mysql date?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. Unfortunately, it is not quite as awesome as PHP's `strtotime`, so you have to give it a format mask to parse:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
        -> '2004-04-31'
```

For your date, I think the mask would be `%M %e %Y %l:%i%p`, depending on whether or not you are expecting short/long month names and 0-based days. Based on your example it could be either:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 30 2006 12:00AM', '%M %e %Y %l:%i%p');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('May 30 2006 12:00AM', '%M %e %Y %l:%i%p') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 2006-05-30 00:00:00                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Check out the [full reference table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the mask options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use STR_TO_DATE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

The format should be something like:

```
"%b %d %Y %l:%i%p"
```