# Convert varchar column to date in mysql at database level

Tags: mysql

I have one column `date1` which is *varchar* type
I want this column to `date` type.
I tried changing field but all date is converted to `0000-00-00`.
format is `dd-mm-yyyy` but in *varchar*.

How can I convert the same date format but with date format using sql queries or similar but at database level ?

Comment: I think this topic will be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731456/convert-dates-with-mysql

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column` = str_to_date( `column`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

More about [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

---

Since your column name is `date1`, you can replace `column` with `date1` in the above syntax, and the code shall be:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `date1` = str_to_date( `date1`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

Comment: Wouldn't the column type still be `VARCHAR` though?

Comment: @Brian The OP mentioned that they tried changing column type which corrupted their data. I was suggesting the method to retain the data before changing column type.

Answer (score 18):

The other answers here are risky, because if they go wrong you'll lose your data. A safer way to do this is to create a new field on your database with a DATE (or DATETIME if you need time as well) format, then to run a query like

```
UPDATE `table` SET `my_new_date_field` = STR_TO_DATE( `my_old_data_field`, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

In this way, if the `%d/%m/%Y` bit is wrong, you won't lose your data.

Once you're happy, you can delete the old data field and rename the new one.

Comment: I believe this is the safest route whilst converting from one column datatype to another. Copy to new column -->  Convert Datatype of new column.

Answer (score 5):

use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) Function of MySQL

FIRST you will need to update the value in date format.

```
UPDATE `tbl` SET `date1` = STR_TO_DATE(`date1`, '%d-%m-%Y') WHERE 1=1
```

THEN Convert the field to date.

Most importantly remember to insert date as Y-m-d format, after then.