# How to select all id's that are within one year prior to a date on a second table?

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables with thousands of entries.  I am only interested in id's that fall within a year prior to the date in the second table.  A small example of what I am working with is as follows...
The first looks like this:

```
table A
id test date
1  b    12/28/2009
4  c    12/03/2006
```

The second table looks like this:

```
table B
id date
1  2/03/2010
4  3/12/2008
```

I want to retrieve all id's from the first table that fall within one year prior to the date on table two.  So for example in this case id 1 would be selected but not id 4.  So far this is the code I have tried.

```
Select * FROM A,B 
WHERE (A.id = B.id AND A.date BETWEEN B.date-INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND B.date);
```

When I run this query I get an empty set.  Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and what I should do to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Your query looks correct. I inserted your data to a test DB and it returns only 1 row. What is the data type for the date columns?

Comment: @Galz, in both tables it is varchar.  Do I need to change the data type for it to work correctly?  If so is there an easy way to do this?  Or is there a way I can do this without changing the data type?

Comment: varchar is a bad way to store dates. To perform date calculations on varchar you need to cast it to dates before doing any calculation...  To convert the varchar columns to date columns see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level

Comment: Your syntax looks a bit wierd. Can you give this a try?

`Select * FROM A,B 
WHERE (A.id = B.id AND A.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(B.date, INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND B.date);`

Comment: @Galz, thank you I will check that out.  I have just been reading about it being a bad way to store dates in some other threads.  I am working with data that was set up prior to me and am also fairly new to this.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you MUST keep the table structure as is, this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(a.date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(b.date, '%m/%d/%Y') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
AND STR_TO_DATE(b.date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Otherwise, read this thread to convert the dates from varchar to date:
[Convert varchar column to date in mysql at database level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level)