# MySQL Not Sorting By Time Correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a MySQL database table that has times (just time of the day ex. "15:45:00") however when I am sorting by time, it doesn't seem to order the rows correctly in order of time.  Here is a screenshot from the query:

```
SELECT * FROM stop_times ORDER BY day ASC, departure_time ASC
```

[image: Query Results]

Do I need to cast the column in a certain form or convert the time in a way for this to work?

Comment: The column is varchar?

Comment: @james yes day is an int and the departure_time is a varchar.  I'm guessing that is the problem?

Comment: Yup good guess, take a lookt at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level

Comment: I would see if the [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) data type is more suitable.

Comment: Also MySQL has (even in the 5.7 version) a few bugs in the order by. My advice is to switch MariaDB to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Are you sure these are just "times of the day" - 24:14:00, 25:14:00 & 25:25:00 seem strange to me

Comment: @PaulF yes they are. They are public transit departure times and for late night service the transit agencies include departure times over 24:00:00 to indicate late night service without having to change the date

Comment: @james I tried your suggestions however the problem persists (Time formats are now 14:56:10.000000) after I switched the column type to TIME and reimported the data.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You might have to format the time value, see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71373/3)

Comment: @james that solved the problem completely! Thank you!