# Convert SQL string into Model datetime in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I'm using Django rest framework to expose a database as API, The database was created manually before the Django implementation. By error, a charfield is storing a DateTime data as a string, My model is unmanaged so that the database structure is not changed, however, I need to use the DateTime field as DateTime, not as a string so that I'll be able to filter the records by date.

Can anybody help me out to check how to cast the value as datetime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert varchar column to date in mysql at database level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level)

Comment: No, as I'm using django to create de DB hits, I have no way to modify the SQL generated by the framework.

Comment: That contradicts what you said yourself "_The database was created manually before the Django implementation_" and "_My model is unmanaged_", if your model is unmanaged then you can only use SQL to modify it. After which you will modify the model code correspondingly.