# What is equivalent of strtotime in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-format

I have a date in my first table with this format `2016-12-20`
i need to compare it with another date in my second table with this format

```
 2016-12-21 18:40:22
```

in php i can change this format with

`$date =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));`

What is equivalent of **strtotime** in **SQL** or how can i compare 2 dates with different format in mysql?

i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731456/convert-dates-with-mysql) and tried this

```
select STR_TO_DATE(date, '%y-%m-%d') from second_table;
```

but it returns NULL

Comment: @vkp it returns NULL When i use that methode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)**

you may need to use `date_format()`