# Like with Date Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has dates stored as text and not as a date_time.  I want to select rows that happened today.  I can hard code the date, but obvious I want to do it dynamically.

`SELECT * FROM view WHERE anniversary LIKE '%09-07'`

`SELECT * FROM view WHERE anniversary LIKE '%' + DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%m-%d")`

Comment: A better idea surely would be to convert the column to be a proper datetime column. Then this kind of query would be trivial.

Comment: Not sure what you're question is specifically but take a look at  this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731456/convert-dates-with-mysql]

Comment: try  WHERE MONTH(anniversary ) = MONTH(now()) and DAY(anniversary ) = DAY(now());  if anniversary  is a date or datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The month and day operators can be used:

```
SELECT * from view WHERE MONTH(anniversary) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(anniversary) = DAY(NOW())
```

if the column is of type `varchar` the `STR_TO_DATE` function can be used to turn it into a date:

```
SELECT * from view WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(anniversary,'%Y-%m-%d')) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(STR_TO_DATE(anniversary,'%Y-%m-%d')) = DAY(NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks STR_TO_DATE() worked.  This is not my database, I am only writing queries against it.  Agreed the data should be stored as date_time, but it isn't.  It is what it is.

Comment: Great! Could you mark it as answer/upvote it so others can find this solution? @RobF.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be storing dates as `date`s, not as strings.

But, if they are stored as strings, you can use a comparison like this:

```
where right(anniversary_datestring, 5) = str_to_date(curdate(), '%m-%d')
```

But, I recommend fixing your data.  If the values are in the format YYYY-MM-DD, simply do:

```
alter table t modify column anniversary date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,
convert string to date and check in where clause

```
SELECT * FROM view WHERE STR_TO_DATE(anniversary, '%d-%m-%Y') = CURDATE()
```